# How to receive data from nested components?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a structure of nested components, like this:

```
<component A>
  <button "save data">
  <component B>
    <form>
      <component C>
        <input/>
        <input/>
        <input/>
      </component C>
      <component D>
        <input/>
        <input/>
        <input/>
      </component D>
    </form>
   </component B>
</component A>
```

Inputs represent `v-text-field` from `Vuetify`.
I would like to receive data from inputs after clicking the button. How to do that in `Vue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to share data across multiple components it's worth looking into Vuex, which centralizes your data and makes it easier to manage:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/

If your app is simple enough you can use an event bus:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced

The documentation there suggests using Vuex though unless it's a very simple case.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Non-flux-state-management-use-with-caution